# Is there any way to regenerate either .pb or .meta file from .index and .ckpt file?

Tags: python-3.x, object-detection, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

I downloaded a code from github which contains .index file and checkpoint file(the network is trained using tensorflow 2.1 and python 3.7). But it doesn't contain the .meta or .pb file. Is there any way to regenerate either .pb or .meta file from .index and checkpoint file?

Answer (score 1):

This might be very specific, but as you tagged object-detection-api this might work:

You can check out [export_inference_graph.py](http://%20https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_inference_graph.py) from the object_detection API.

With an example call like this:

```
python export_inference_graph.py \
--input_type image_tensor \
--pipeline_config_path path/to/ssd_inception_v2.config \
--trained_checkpoint_prefix path/to/model.ckpt \
--output_directory path/to/exported_model_directory
```

This will work if you have a model which is based on the object detection api and already trained there. So e.g. if you found a model in the [model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) you can find the configs in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs) and use it as the .config file in the above call.

If you are using a tf lite model, you can look at [export_tflite_ssd_graph.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph.py)